# R: sum of unknown number of matrices

Tags: r

I am trying to write a loop that will summarize my set of matrices that all start with the same name plus a number (e.g. "day11"). However, in each run of the loop the number of matrices varies.

Without the loop it can be done once like this:

```
combmat<-(day1+day3+day4+day5+day6+day8+day9+day10+day11+day12+day13+day14+day15+day16+day17+day18+day19+day20+day22+day23+day24+day25+day26+day27+day28+day29)
```

I have tried

```
sum(list=ls(pattern="^day"))
```

without any luck ...

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
day1<-matrix(c(1:4),2,2)
day2<-matrix(c(1:4),2,2)
day3<-matrix(c(1:4),2,2)
day4<-matrix(c(1:4),2,2)

list=ls(pattern="^day")

res<-lapply(list,"get")

do.call("sum",res)

> do.call("sum",res)
[1] 40
```

will work for you

`get` returns the value of a named object. So `get("x")` would return the variable x

Comment: Great! That worked.
However, I had to use:
Reduce("+",res)
to retain a matrix as a result.

Comment: my mistake! I wrote sum in the initial question. Thanks again!